# Adding a registration page before the tabViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that is working good.

Now before I open the tabController, I want to check if the user is registered, if not I want to open a registration page (RegistrationController) and then go back to my tabView.

How can I do this, since the TabBarController can only be the first page.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can have a viewController(VC1) pushing another viewController (VC2) and in `viewDidLoad` of VC2 u can add ur tabbar programmatically.

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

VC3 *object1 = [[VC3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC3" bundle:nil];
VC4 *object2 = [[VC4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC4" bundle:nil];


tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];


tabBarController.delegate = self;
[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"title"];
[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"title"];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[object1 release];
[object2 release];
```

also u can do this

in the `viewDidLoad` of the `tabBarController` (default view), u can check a variable, if its 0 (i.e. user is not registered), then u can `presentModalViewController` with a registration form.

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overlay, over the table view controller (another view which will make the table view not visible, since it will be behind the view you're adding). On succcessfull login / registration, you remove the overlay view.

Comment: how can i put an overlay that hides the tabs (its a TabViewController, not a tableViewController)